# Uptex, issue with fonts

Tags: japanese, uplatex

I am actually testing upTex because I have to write some japanese texts with a vertical alignment.
Unfortunately I do not find enough resources about it.
However, I found some examples in some questions in tex.stackexchange, so I `uplatex` this `file.tex` example and obtain a `file.dvi`.
But when I try to `dvipdfmx` it, I obtain this error :

[EDIT 1](result of the `dvipdfmx -v file.dvi`)

```
<FONTMAP:/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>draft.dvi -> draft.pdf
DVI Comment:  TeX output 2019.05.25:1743
<AGL:texglyphlist.txt><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1<cmbx12@14.35pt(TFM:cmbx12)
pdf_font>> Simple font "cmbx12.pfb" enc_id=<builtin,-1> opened at font_id=<cmbx12,0>.
><upjisg-v@13.80pt(TFM:upjisg-v)(VF:upjisg-v(TFM:upgbm-v)<upgbm-v@13.80pt
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+231/600 --dpi 831 upgbm-v
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for upgbm-v.
mktexpk: perhaps upgbm-v is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

dvipdfmx:warning: Could not locate a virtual/physical font for TFM "upgbm-v".
dvipdfmx:warning: >> There are no valid font mapping entry for this font.
dvipdfmx:warning: >> Font file name "upgbm-v" was assumed but failed to locate that font.
dvipdfmx:fatal: Cannot proceed without .vf or "physical" font for PDF output...

No output PDF file written.
```

I am on void-linux and use Texlive 2019.
Here is the minimal example I use :

```
\documentclass{utarticle}
\begin{document}
\section{芥川龍之介「るしへる」}
破提宇子と云う天主教を弁難した書物のある事は、知っている人も少くあるまい。これは
、元和六年、加賀の禅僧巴毗弇なるものの著した書物である。巴毗弇は当初南蛮寺に住し
た天主教徒であったが、その後何かの事情から、DS 如来を捨てて仏門に帰依する事になっ
た。書中に云っている所から推すと、彼は老儒の学にも造詣のある、一かどの才子だった
らしい。
\end{document}
```

Comment: works fine for me on windows. Do you have a full texlive 2019? Can you run dvipdfmx -v file to get more message?

Comment: Make sure that the TeX Live package `ptex-fontmaps` is installed. How did you install TeX Live on your Linux box?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited my message with the result of the verbose command.

@egreg I installed the ptex-fontmaps package, but nothing new, the same error message.
My Tex live is installed with the package manager. It is the original package binary.
The upgbm-v font exists in my computer in the texlive directories (verified with a ```find```).
I really do not know why it does not work.

Comment: check if upgbm-v is mentioned in the `kanjix.map`.

Comment: I tried to install void-linux on VirtualBox: *very* unfriendly installer. I gave up.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it is in the map : ```upgbm-v UniJIS-UTF16-V ipaexg.ttf %!PS IPAexGothic``` and I have an ```ipaexg.ttf``` int my texlive directory ```/opt/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/ipaex/ipaexg.ttf```.
@egreg maybe you took an old installer. This one could be unstable. Whatever the installer, it is not an out-of-the-box installer. More like Archlinux.

Comment: and you checked the kanjix.map in texmf-var? Is your texlive up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, my TexLive is up-to-date. Concerning the ```kanjix.map``` in the ```texmf-var```, I generated the file with the command ```updmap-sys``` as written in the header of the file. Now, I have a new error message : ```dvipdfmx:fatal: Could not find encoding file "UniJIS-UTF16-V".```
It seems to refers to the ```upgbm-v UniJIS-UTF16-V ipaexg.ttf %!PS IPAexGothic``` line in the kanjix.map

Comment: the cmap is in my system in a subfolder of fonts/cmap/adobemapping.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I do not understand why I cannot make the relation between the map and the font. All the fonts seems to be in the texmf-dist and not in the texmf-var. What is the difference between them ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well, in addition, it seems it had destroyed everything : now, even XeLaTeX doesn't work anymore, it tried to look for a font with kpathsea instead to looking for local files. I tried to reinstall everything, but nothing change...

Comment: Some news after a while. It was a bug in the last update of TeXlive.